# Decimal representation of $1/n$ includes the string of digits $777$

Tags: number-theory

> Find an integer $n$ with the property that the decimal representation of $1/n$ includes the string of digits $777$.

For $\dfrac{m}{n}$ we can find a string of digits $777$ just by looking at $0.777$ and writing that as a fraction. But how do we do it for $1/n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.** It suffices that $0.00\ldots0777\leq\frac1n<0.00\ldots0778$ for a certain number of zeroes.

> If there are $k$ zeroes, we want $\frac1{778}<\frac n{10^k}\leq\frac1{777}$. This gives an interval of size $\frac1{777}-\frac1{778}=\frac1{777\cdot778}$, which will contain a multiple of $10^{-k}$ as soon as $10^k\geq777\cdot778$.
>  In general, with $a$ instead of $777$ we need $10^k\geq a(a+1)$.
>  Explicitly, this gives $n=\left\lfloor\frac{10^k}a\right\rfloor$ with $k=\lceil\log_{10}(a^2+a)\rceil$, in our case, $n=1287$.

Comment: How do we show it in the general case if we replace $777$ with any positive integer?

Comment: I thought $k = a(a+1)$. How did you get $\lfloor\log_{10}(a^2+a)\rfloor$?

Comment: See edit; I was missing some powers of $10$. The version with log is the right one.

Comment: Why do you want the gap size to contain a multiple of $10^{-k}$?

Comment: We want there to be a multiple of $10^{-k}$ between $1/778$ and $1/777$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{7}{9}=0.777\ldots,\qquad \frac{7}{90}=0.0777\ldots $$
and if we consider
$$ \frac{7}{90000} = 0.0000777\ldots $$ we have
$$ \frac{7}{90000}+\frac{1}{10000} = 0.0001777\ldots $$
with
$$ \frac{7}{90000}+\frac{1}{10000}=\frac{7+9}{90000}=\frac{16}{90000}=\frac{1}{\color{red}{5625}} $$
since $7+9=16$ is a divisor of $9\cdot 10^4$. Even better: since $7+18$ is a divisor of $9\cdot 10^2$,
$$ 0.02\color{red}{777}\ldots=\frac{7}{900}+\frac{2}{100}=\frac{1}{\color{red}{36}}.$$

Comment: This might generalize: The $k$-digit number $n$ is the period of $\frac{n}{10^k-1}$ and also of $\frac{n}{(10^k-1)10^r}+\frac s{10^r}$. Now we only need to achieve $(10^k-1)s+n\mid 10^r$ ...

Answer (score 2):

**Hint 1:** $\frac{7}{9}=0.\bar{7}$.

**Hint 2:** $0.\overline{000..01}=\frac{1}{10^n-1}$.

Now pick some $n \geq 4$ so that $7|10^n-1$ [ for example $n=\phi(7)=6$] and show that 
$$\frac{7}{9} \frac{1}{10^n-1}$$
works.

$n=6$ leads to 
$$\frac{1}{1285713}=0.000000777778...$$

Answer (score 1):

Notice $777 = 7\times 111$ and for any integer $m\in \mathbb{Z}_{+}$,

- $111\,|\,\overbrace{999,\cdots,999}^{3m\text{ digits}}$
- $7\,|\,\underbrace{999,\cdots,999}_{6m\text{ digits}} = (10^m)^6 - 1$ by Fermat's little theorem.

$n = \frac{999,999}{777} = 1287$ is one solution for the problem. In fact
$\frac{1}{1287} = 0.\overline{000,777}$.

Comment: There are two $n$'s with different meanings...

Comment: @barto  changed, thanks for pointing that out.